# How To Center An Oversized Image Within Browser Window With Inline HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, inline

I'm trying to center an image that is 1920px wide within the browser window. They don't need it to fit within the window so the width:100% won't work. I also have to do this with inline html. I've tried: `vertical-align`, `text-align`, `margin-left/right:auto`, `position` and `overflow`. Maybe I'm just doing it wrong? The latest test code is below. I couldn't find any previously asked questions that worked but if there's something already out there, please let me know.

```html
<div>
    <a title="TITLE" href="{{store direct_url=bras.html}}" target="_self">
        <img style="vertical-align: middle;" title="TITLE" src="/IMAGE/PATH/HERE/MY-IMAGE.jpg" alt="ALT" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You want it centered vertically and horizontally, regardless of window size?

Comment: CSS3 has a nice attribute called background-size:cover which you might want to use to achieve what you want. The only problem is that you will need your image to be used as background in CSS as background: url(imageLocation/imag.jpg);

Comment: The image doesn't need to fit within the window? Do you mean the image should not be resized? The window should be a viewport where you can see the center part of the image?

Comment: why must it be defined inline?

Comment: They want it to be centered vertically in the window. I think what they want to do is something similar to parallex. Their site isn't responsive, I think it just shows a different "home" page when you get to a breaking point at mobile size. I don't have access to the CSS or javascript. So everything has to be done in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Some nice attribute in CSS3 can help with that. I wrote the code in a well structured form so that you can easily read it. Using inline Style will not really make this readable and I strongly suggest you put your style in a separate class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="linktoyourimage.jpg" alt="" title="" />
<div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    object-fit: cover; /* Not supported in IE */
}
```

The important thing is that you need to define a width and height to your `div`, which is your image container. That should be set at `100%` to have a width that fits your screen. You will notice I used `height:100vh`. This one makes the div take the whole height of your browser. You can read more on Viewport units [here](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/).

Next you want your image to fill that box, and therefore it takes a width and height of `100%`. However we make use of left and translate to center the image and finally `object-fit` which make the image fit in the box. Basically what `object-fit` does is crop the image to fit the box without stretching or resizing it.

I'll leave it up to you to make it inline if you want. Below is a JSFiddle if you want to see how the code works.

**JS Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/whw8n56d/3/

Comment: quibble: 100vh, is not to take the whole height of the monitor, rather the whole height of the browser (and in some cases the browser includes/not includes the scroll bar in the bottom) window... which might be a bit semantically nitpicky but may trip up some people

Comment: Woops my bad. I meant browser but typed monitor for some reason. I'll edit that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: also depending on support object-fit is not supported in IE at all. so this might not be a great solution, but might fit the requirements

Comment: Yep there is no IE support for Object-fit. I guess OP could use JS in that case